# Retrieving data through associative class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables,  **Animal** and **Circus**  that have a many-to-many relationship which engenders the  associative class **Contract**, and I have a **Breed** class that is associated with **Animal** by the one-to-many relationship.
How can i find the **Breed** that has the max of Animals having figured in Circuses.

I've tried this :

```
var req = from Animal A in Contract
                     group A by A.Breed into g
                     select max { g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

but it's not working
what i mean is , if for exemple we have:

```
**Animal_FK**      **Circus_FK**     **Salary**    **Contract_ date**      
----------          ----------      ------------    -------------------

   S3                  C10             3000           2015-12-12

   S1                  C12             5000           2010-10-17

   D2                  C18             4000           2016-02-22

   B4                  C85             3500           2018-09-30

   S2                   C6              2700           2014-05-10


Animal_key        Name          
-------------  -------------          
    S1            Python 
    S2            Cobra              
    S3            Boa              
    D1            Bulldog              
    D2            Labrador              
    B1            Owl
    B2            Dove   





Beer_Key      Name         Description    
----------  ---------    ----------------                    
   S          Snake            reptile      
   D          Dog              pet     
   B          Birds            flying animals
```

the result of the query will be **Snake**

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: @jarlh Because it's a sql request

Comment: That's not SQL. Perhaps linq?

Comment: Do you mean the breed with the most animals that have figured in circuses (have one or more contracts), or the breed with the most appearances (highest total number of contracts)? I think we'll need some sample data and your expected results.

Comment: It's the breed with the highest total number of contracts

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the sample data, @MarTech.  So now - you talk about classes and you talk about tables.  And the code you posted looks like linq.  So are we talking about linq against some CLR classes, or sql, or linq-to-sql?  Or maybe even Entity Framework?

Comment: i'm working with Entity Framework

Comment: OK - I've just posted an answer based on plain old CLR objects.  If this doesn't help then maybe someone will pick this up on the Entity-Framework tag ... unfortunately I don't have specific knowledge in EF.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming some POCO's here.  I'll not provide the additional details like Salary etc., just the minimum.

```
public class Breed
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Breed Breed { get; set; }
}

public class Circus
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
    public Animal Performer { get; set; }
    public Circus Venue { get; set; }
}
```

Then set up some data that represents what you have above.

```
var breeds = new[]
{
    new Breed {Name = "Snake"},
    new Breed {Name = "Dog"},
    new Breed {Name = "Bird"}
};

var animals = new[]
{
    new Animal{Name="Boa", Breed = breeds[0]},     // 0
    new Animal{Name="Python", Breed = breeds[0]},  // 1
    new Animal{Name="Cobra", Breed = breeds[0]},   // 2
    new Animal{Name="Bulldog", Breed = breeds[1]}, // 3
    new Animal{Name="Labrador", Breed = breeds[1]},// 4
    new Animal{Name="Dove", Breed = breeds[1]},    // 5
    new Animal{Name="Owl", Breed = breeds[2]},     // 6
};

var circuses = new[]
{
    new Circus {Name = "C1"},
    new Circus {Name = "C2"},
    new Circus {Name = "C3"},
    new Circus {Name = "C4"},
    new Circus {Name = "C5"},
};

var contracts = new[]
{
    new Contract {Performer = animals[0], Venue = circuses[0]},
    new Contract {Performer = animals[1], Venue = circuses[1]},
    new Contract {Performer = animals[2], Venue = circuses[2]},
    new Contract {Performer = animals[4], Venue = circuses[3]},
    new Contract {Performer = animals[6], Venue = circuses[4]},
};
```

Then this is how you get the most represented Breed:

```
var mostRepresentedBreed = (
        from contract in contracts
        group contract by contract.Animal.Breed
        into contractsByBreed
        orderby contractsByBreed.Count() descending
        select contractsByBreed.Key
    ).FirstOrDefault();

var theWinnerIs = mostRepresentedBreed.Name;
```

Hope this helps.
Brett.